# Angular - Testing an @Input with a set attached to it

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, testing, karma-runner

I have a component which takes an argument as a sort of directive to set the size of the `<div>` within its template, the only problem now is that I am unsure how to test it?

I called my component like this, where `small` can be replaced with other pre-defined sizes such as `medium/large` etc:

```
<spinner small></spinner>
```

Then I take this as an `@Input(<size>)` and perform a set to change a size variable that is then passed into an `[ngStyle]` to change the CSS of the displayed component size.

**component.ts**

```
size: number;

@Input('small') set small(value) {
  this.size = !value ? 25 : this.size;
}

get getSize() {
  const myStyle = {
    width: this.size + 'px',
    height: this.size + 'px'
  };
  return myStyle;
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div [ngStyle]="getSize"></div>
```

I have successfully tested the `get getSize()` function, but I have become  a bit stuck around the `@Input(<val>) set` functions :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To know what test to make, ask yourself this question :

> What does my [feature/component/service/function/variable/...] do ?

In this case, your setters can answer with

> As a setter with an `Input` decorator, I should set the value of the `size` variable if my own value is undefined. If my own value is defined, I should fall back to the default value.

This means that your setter tests will look like this :

```
it('should set size variable with value undefined', () => {
  component.size = 10;
  component.small = '';
  epxect(component.size).toEqual(25);
});

it('should not change size variable with value defined', () => {
  component.size = 10;
  component.small = 'ff';
  epxect(component.size).toEqual(10);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-template-gyv3ed?file=app%2Fhello.component.spec.ts)

In order to spyOn getter/setter properties, you can use [jasmine spyOnProperty](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.6/global.html#spyOnProperty):

[image]

So in your example we have: `obj -> component, propertyName -> 'small', accessType -> 'set'` :

```
  it('call small setter method', () => {
    const small = spyOnProperty(component, 'small', 'set'); // just spyOn setter method of small
    component.size = 10; // set initial value of size to 10

    component.small = 'large'; // set small property which as expected - should call setted method

    // we expect that `small` setter method will be called 
    //  with 'large' argument, since we setted it before 
    expect(small).toHaveBeenCalledWith('large'); 

    // we also expect, that the logic of your setter method works correctly: `this.size = !value ? 25 : this.size;`
    // since we pass value, your `this.size` will not change
    expect(component.size).toBe(10); 
  });
```

**Edit**

This is another test in case when we pass to setter argument an empty string:

```
it('call small setter method 2', () => {
    const small = spyOnProperty(component, 'small', 'set').and.callThrough();

    component.small = '';

    expect(small).toHaveBeenCalledWith('');
    expect(component.size).toBe(25);
  });
```

As expected - the `small` setter will be called with '' empty string and the `size` property will be 25 because of this: `this.size = !value ? 25 : this.size;`

Comment: I'm not sure about this... I mean, it passes; but the test sets the size and then calls the size? like `component.size = 10` and then `expect(component.size).toEqual(10)`... Of course it will be 10. Or is this just the way that it should be done, because that's all the `@Input()` is doing? I may just be dense :P - Also, I had no idea you could test on stackblitz! That's awesome!

Comment: "but the test sets the size and then calls the size" - what do you mean by calls size? there is no any calls. I've edited the answer and added explanation, check it out.

Comment: Apologies, I meant that the test sets the size and then checks the size that has just been set. Kind of like, putting a ball into a box and then checking that there is a ball in a box. If that makes more sense.

Comment: Ah I understand more from what your comments on the code now say! That makes more sense.

Comment: Yep, the aim is to make sure, that you setter logic does not change `this.size` if we pass a `value` argument to it: `this.size = !value ? 25 : this.size;` - this ternary will just reset `this.size` with the previous value of size.

Comment: Could you show me how I would change the test such that I actually want the size to = 25? I am attempting myself, not just mooching jut FYI :P

Comment: Sure. I've updated my answer and added new example for this

Comment: Ah that makes sense! I was attempting `component.small` with no value and also `component.small = null`. Consoling out shows a blank line, so I wasn't sure if it was null or an empty string. Thanks for that :-)

Comment: I'd say your test is **"too specific"** : it is indeed the "right way" to write a test, but you're relying on the implementation of getters and setters by Typescript. The purpose of a unit testing is to test a single unit and make abstraction of other code, and in this case, you're testing if Typescript does its job (which isn't your job)

Comment: Agree, but the question is about testing setter method and I've tried to help.

Comment: @sherlock.92 that's why I didn't downvote : your answer is technically valid, I'm just giving my opinion on it from what I have learnt myself !